# Using FireBug for a website with frames

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

I downloaded Firebug and attempted to use it to debug JS for a site that uses frames.

My understanding is when I go to the Script tab in Firebug, I would see the JS functions on the aspx and the JS in any files that are included and I would be able to set breakpoints.

However, all I see on this site is:

```
</head>
<frameset>
 <frame src="../company/HostPage.aspx name="mainFrame">
 <noframes></noframes>
</frameset>
</html>
```

Am I understanding Firebug correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two menu strips in Firebug.  When you select the "Script" tab, above that is a menu strip that contains the name of the current file.  If you click on that, you'll see a list of all files downloaded on the current page.  Select the file loaded into the frame you want to debug, and it's contents will appear in the text box.  You'll see the entire contents, not just the script blocks.