# Is there an add-on to IE or Firefox or any application that would easily help list html frames in a website?

Tags: html, iframe, frame, add-on

I was wondering if there are any applications out there that would help easily list the frames in a website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use firefox with firebug.  Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623779/using-firebug-for-a-website-with-frames/623798#623798) for a quick idea about viewing files loaded in frames.

Comment: @xzuroski: Thanks. I was using Firebug already, but didn't realize there was a right-click option that would let me select particular frames. Thanks!